# Handle text Colour in WooCommerce variations?

Tags: css, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Have one problem that don t know how to resolve. Have [product](https://www.muaythaimall.com/shop/fairtex-embroidered-muay-thai-shorts-phoenix-bs0642/) (XS variation) that is "non in stock" but have selected "Allow but notify customer" So want to make that variation in yellow color, like is shown in image bellow.

[image]

Have this function for that:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 
'grey_out_variations_when_is_backorder', 10, 2 );
function grey_out_variations_when_is_backorder( $grey_out, $variation ) {

if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() && $variation-
 >backorders_require_notification() )
$grey_out = false; // Here text variation need to be yellow.

return $grey_out;
}
```

but dont resolved nothing, because grayout can get only 2 values, true or false. So i used this CSS:

```
.sbOptions li span.sbDisabled {
 color:red!important;
 }
.sbOptions li a {
color:green!important;
}
```

so can control gray in and gray out variations only. No possiblity for third option that i want to make.  Want variations that is: “out of stock” + “allow, backorder but notify” = yellow background & can be selected. Currently that variations is in green colour, because i dont found a way how to handle colour for that variations. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your code, but you can test this?
Use sub class, or check your class if they are affected or not in element inspector

```css
.content {
background:gray;
padding:5px;
margin:5px 0;
}

.content div {
  margin:5px 0;
}

.content div.blue {
  color:blue;
}

.content div.red {
  color:red;
}

.content.test div {
  color:yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="red">Test</div>
  <div class="blue">Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>

<div class="content test">
  <div class="red">Test</div>
  <div class="blue">Test</div>
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Class is named: sbOptions i dont know how to handle that? Any suggestion. Have posted link in first post.

Comment: I have add this css `color: red !important;` in `.sbOptions li.sbDisabled a` and I have added "sbDisabled" in the li concerned, you just need to add "sbDisabled" to some li for affect the link

Comment: How that will handle only available on backorder products ? i dont see any selector that point only to that group of products? i cant modify that classes because is auto generated from WooCommerce. Other suggestions?

Comment: ha, you can't modify the JS or php ? if (stock == true) $color = "green", else $color = red  and  replace the `... <li>...` by `...<li class=$color>...`

Comment: Its not problem to handle "in-stock" variable, its problem to handle "backorders_require_notification"  class, because WooCommerce dont have provided class for that thing. Currently all variations that have :
Allow Backorders and 
Allow but notify customer

 are marked with green color. I need to mark "Allow but notify customer" in yellow. Is possible?

Comment: Bad luck.. I dont found nothing on Google how to handle that. :(